# Kickstarter clone in Drupal?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, drupal

I would like to create a Kickstarter type clone in terms of functionality.

Can Drupal produce a ***crude*** prototype?

Or suck it up, hit the books and learn python/django or ruby/rails.

I appreciate any and all input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal would likely handle the basic concept of listings rather adeptly, but you'd need to write plenty of glue code to make it match the exact functionality you want. It would, in fact, be easier to write it from scratch than to force a tool to do a different job.

Go for a full-fledged web app framework.

Comment: Sorry Matchu, but you are wrong.
People who know Drupal don't need to write plenty of glue code. On the contrary - when you know your Drupal, you almost don't need any coding.
And for the kickstarter.com based on Drupal - just look at here - http://drupaldojo.com/session/drupals-payment-api-and-how-we-built-kickstarter-functionality-drupal

Comment: @Shushu: Meh. Since it's a subjective answer, there's no right/wrong to be found. I'd maintain that it's a better solution to write a custom web app that uses a payment API than to make a CMS act like a web app. Just because Drupal has a payment API doesn't mean that it's therefore best-suited for the job; after all, there's much more to Kickstarter than displaying projects and accepting payment. I'd go with a nice, simple web framework here, and pull in a similarly powerful payment API. After all, I've only heard of people having problems maintaining a "web app" with a Drupal core.

Comment: I too would lke to say Drupal is more than a CMS. It is actually a very capable framework, (api.drupal.org), albeit you may need to know a bit about it before you get started. I do ALL my php dev using Drupal as a framework.